# How to reinstate dualboot after upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, upgrade, windows-8, uefi

I had a dual-boot setup of Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8 on my Asus Vivobook. Initially the  dual-boot setup asked for some tweaking as Windows 8 insisted on being UEFI started. But it worked lateron.

This morning, I was silly to accept the proposed upgrade to Windows 8.1. Now windows has replaced the boot manager and I no longer get asked if I want to boot to Ubuntu. The computer boots straight to Windows.

As I really require both OS's, I have been trying to create a functional dual boot situation. I partly succeeded, but for the time being, I am stuck in a situation where the Grub options are shown, and only Ubuntu can be started.

Whenever I try any of the Windows booting methods provided in the grub menu, I get a nice blue screen with the message:

```
Your PC needs to be repaired
Error code 0xc0000225
```

After Return, next nice blue screen says:

```
File:<Windows<system32<winload.efi is missing with same error code.
```

I have CSM enabled in BIOS, as well as "secure boot" option.

So, how do I reinstate dualboot after upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) Yours is basically a special-case of the referred-to question, but the same solution should work.

Comment: This is a duplicate to http://askubuntu.com/questions/384592/windows-8-1-upgrade-destroyed-my-ubuntu-machine/399719#399719

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix the  windows bootloader.So boot windows installation disk then click on the **Repair your computer** option at the startup.

After that click on the *command-prompt* option.In that command-prompt run the following commands to fix the windows bootloader,

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

And then try [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Answer (score 0):

You can use boot repair to fix boot issues.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It should get things sorted out for you.